# PHP Curl to get page contenct

Tags: php, curl

Im trying to fetch content of a website about a tourament. I want to display the results on a temporary page.

I'm tying to fetch this page:
http://www.tournamentsoftware.com/sport/draw.aspx?id=600CA297-99CA-4420-AE1A-698BA10C39B0&draw=1

I want to return the content of this page, and afterwards fetch the specific table with the fixtures.

The script i'm using returns a 404 Not found error, while the url is present.

My script:

```
function nxs_cURLTest($url, $msg, $testText){
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/5.0)");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION,3); // Apparently 2 or 3
$response = curl_exec($ch);
$errmsg = curl_error($ch);
$cInfo = curl_getinfo($ch);
curl_close($ch);
echo "Testing ... ".$url." - ".$cInfo['url']."<br />";
if (stripos($response, $testText)!==false)
echo "....".$msg." - OK<br />";
else
{
echo "....<b style='color:red;'>".$msg." - Problem</b><br /><pre>";
print_r($errmsg);
print_r($cInfo);
print_r(htmlentities($response));
echo "</pre>There is a problem with cURL. You need to contact your server admin or hosting provider.";
}
}
nxs_cURLTest("http://www.tournamentsoftware.com/sport/draw.aspx?id=600CA297-99CA-4420-AE1A-698BA10C39B0&draw=1", "HTTPS to Toernooi.nl", 'link rel="canonical" href="http://www.tournamentsoftware.com/sport/draw.aspx?id=600CA297-99CA-4420-AE1A-698BA10C39B0&draw=1"');
```

Can anyone help me on this one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the following on xampp win7 with chrome and it returned data

```
$url = 'http://www.tournamentsoftware.com/sport/draw.aspx?id=600CA297-99CA-4420-AE1A-698BA10C39B0&draw=1';
echo curl_scrap($url);
function curl_scrap($url) {
  $ch = curl_init();
  $timeout = 5;
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
  $data = curl_exec($ch);
  curl_close($ch);
  return $data;
}
```

It did not return the same source as just using chrome to hit url, as function doesn't set anything like user agent field etc, but returned the data you want, just a quick and dirty test.

Comment: thanks for your answer, strange thing is that this script returns a 404 on my server, and it does not seem to work. Locally it works perfect indeed.

Comment: @mastahb just uploaded to server, it worked just fine. your server config could be the problem. do a `curl_getinfo($ch)` to get the response code returned by the server. also the `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` may have failed. try saving response to a file.